# Why is my object value null?

Tags: c#, object, null

First, I have to mention that I'm new to c# language so I don't know well what each and every property means or does.

I'm building a test application for math formulas. I encountered various problems but the current one is that when I try to modify the text property of a label, the application throws an exception which says "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" It's true that I haven't manually declared the label, but dragged it on the form, but I always did that and haven't encounter problems. 
What might be the cause of all the objects's values being set to null? 
I attached a picture with the program in debug mode.

I observed that in other similar application that I have the values of the objects aren't null.

Below is the print screen with my application in debug mode, and the other image is from the other application. As I don't have enough reputation, I can't post images directly.

I searched and read all over the internet for answers but I haven't found anything helpful. I'd like to change the null value from my objects to a reference, if I can. Is thay possible?

I hope I was clear enough, if not, I will edit my question. 
Thank you!

https://i.stack.imgur.com/dV7rm.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/jMmVM.png

Can't believe I didn't observe that! Thank you very much, now it works! If I have anymore questions about my application (which I do) should I create another post or can I ask here (without deleting my initial question) ?

Comment: It's not that your `label1` is `null`. It's what you're setting it with that is `null`. The `Convert.ToString(Class1.c1) +` part has something that is `null`. You should look into that.

Comment: what is that "something" which is null? The Class1.c1 variable and all the others are of type int and aren't null. If you could be a bit more specific, thank you.

Comment: I can't be more specific because you're error is covering up that line. Something on the right side of that equal sign is `null`.

Comment: this.label1.Text = Convert.ToString(Class1.c1) + Convert.ToString(Class1.c2) + Convert.ToString(Class1.c3) + Convert.ToString(Class1.c4); This is the code line

Comment: Well, either `c1`, `c2`, `c3`, or `c4` is null. And if they are all of type `int`, you should be calling `c1.ToString()` instead of the `Convert.ToString()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The instance will be created once InitializeComponent will have been called.

The code in your constructor is executed before it.

You should probably leave the constructor with just InitializeComponent and do your initialization in the Load event handler.

Answer (score 0):

The objects on the form are created in the InitializeComponents() method that is called in the contructor. Move your code after the InitializeComponents() call.